# Import 32-bit dll in 64-bit Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, 64-bit, dllimport

I need to import dll in my WinForm application.

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(uint reserved,out IRunningObjectTable pprot);
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved,out IBindCtx pctx);
```

This works for 32-bit OS.

I have 64-bit OS but I have installed 32-bit .dlls.
I do not have 64-bit .dlls. Do not have `ole64.dll`.

If there is a way to load 32-bit dll in 64-bit OS?

Comment: The 64-bit version of that DLL is still named ole32.dll.  These OS dlls are kept in separate directories.  The 32-bit flavor lives in c:\windows\syswow64, the 64-bit flavor lives in c:\windows\system32.  Not a typo.  The [file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) ensures that the correct one is found at runtime.  So the only problem is that you don't have a problem.

Comment: This question saves time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't load 64-bit code inside a 32-bit process and vice versa.

If you need to interop with 32-bit code inside your process you need to run 32-bit as well. The default configuration for a .NET Project in newer VS versions is for your program to run in 32-bit mode on a 32-bit OS and in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit OS.

You can change that on the Project options, Build, Platform target. Change "Any CPU" to "x86":
[image]

That being said, is your problem really with ole32.dll? You should have a 64-bit copy of that DLL in your %windir%\System32 folder if you are on a 64-bit OS. And in this case the 32-bit version is in %windir%\SysWOW64 folder.